# Java Exception generates compiler error, but replacing type of exception does not generate a compiler error

Tags: java, exception

Good day all, I have this piece of exception handling code, from the **Java OCA SE 8** certification book by *Boyarski and Selikoff*. I don't understand 1 detail and 1 variation of the code:

```
          try {
              throw new RuntimeException();
          } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    29:       throw new RuntimeException();
          } finally {
    31:      throw new Exception();
          }
```

As is, the compiler issues this message:

```
error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
          throw new Exception();
```

On the other hand, if I delete line 31, it all goes well. So, my first question is: How come line 29, an uncaught exception (I think) is ok for the compiler ? Is it because the `RuntimeException()` had already been caught before ?

The second question is: If I replace line 31 with

```
          throw new RuntimeException();
```

It all goes well. But why ?  I don't have any `try/catch` inside the `finally` block.

Any help to answer these two questions is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/understanding-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java

Comment: [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)